# How should I store a Firestore DocumentReference that I use multiple times?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### The database

Hey! 
I have a Firestore database with two collections: `users` and `groups`.
[image]

Each user is linked to a group. So, of course my flutter app is fetching the group's `DocumentReference` multiple times in the app, so it can use it to fetch other data from the database.
What I have currently

---

This is how I am currently fetching the data. This screen is the base for many screens in the app, so each screen has one `groupDocRef`, which isn't very efficient - I would like them to all have the same one.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shavtzak/data/soldier.dart';
import 'package:shavtzak/widgets/placeholder.dart';

import '../constants.dart';
import '../utils.dart';

/// A base [StatefulWidget] for any screen that wants to display data from Firestore.
abstract class BaseFirestoreState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  /// The current [FirebaseAuth] user.
  User? _user;

  StreamSubscription<User?>? _authStateChangeListener;

  DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>? _nullableGroupDoc;

  /// A [DocumentReference] to the user's group doc.
  late DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> groupDocRef;

  @override
  @nonVirtual
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Begin to listen to any user change event.
    if (_authStateChangeListener == null) {
      _authStateChangeListener = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
        if (user != null) {
          _user = user;

          Utils.getGroupDoc(_user!).then((value) => {setState(() => _nullableGroupDoc = value)});
        }
      });
    }

    // If the group doc is null, show empty screen.
    if (_nullableGroupDoc == null)
      return NoDataPlaceholder();
    // Else return the child.
    else
      groupDocRef = _nullableGroupDoc!;
    return buildWithDoc(context);
  }

  /// The child's widget.
  ///
  /// Replaces the default [build] method.
  Widget buildWithDoc(BuildContext context);

  /// Returns a [Stream] of lists of [Soldier]s.
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getSoldiersStream() {
    return groupDocRef.collection(Constants.dbColSoldiers).snapshots();
  }

  /// Extracts and returns a list of soldiers from a Firestore [QuerySnapshot].
  List<Soldier> soldierListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
      Soldier? sol;
      // If there is no data, return null.
      if (doc.data() == null) {
        sol = null;
      }
      // Else, return the extracted soldier.
      else {
        sol = Soldier.fromMap(doc.data()!, doc.id);
      }

      return sol!;
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_authStateChangeListener != null) {
      _authStateChangeListener!.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

### The Question

Since reading the same `DocumentReference` a lot of times in a single app session isn't a good idea, I would like to know how should I create a global reference so that I call the database only once.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one uses `static` for sharing a variable between all instances of a class:

`static late DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> groupDocRef;`

Access with:

`YOUR_CLASS.groupDocRef = ...`

`var bla = YOUR_CLASS.groupDocRef;`